# Old, off-topic, locked, low views, low score - delete?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, moderation, historical-lock

## Should we delete this question?

https://stackoverflow.com/q/279619/541136

My question: Why not delete it? (Or perhaps why can't we vote to delete?)

I try to [moderate](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges?tab=moderation) as I come across content organically. I found this one as I clicked through the Related links on the sidebar.

## Analysis

I think it should be deleted because it is my impression that

- it has relatively low views relative to others locked for historical reasons (and thus isn't actually historical).
- it has low votes.
- the top answers are jokey-nonanswers.
- off-topic content encourages more of the same (in spite of the "historical message").
- it is potentially wasting space on the Related section of the sidebar.

## The Question:

**Can we delete this question?**

## Resolution Update:

George Stocker (who answered below) deleted it.

Comment: Historical locking is specifically designed to avoid encouraging more off-topic content, and I don't see why it wouldn't work at that. The other reasons are valid, though. (In particular, the votes are ridiculously low for a historical lock, by at least an order of magnitude.)

Comment: I'm in favor of getting rid of it.  There's nothing here to indicate a valid reason to have kept it alive, quite frankly...

Comment: FYI: page now gone

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This question does not meet our criteria for a historical lock. Back when it was introduced, we went through a period where we were much more liberal with it than we are now. Now we reserve it for the true off topic gems.

This is not one of those.